# Ubuntu12.04 has libc6 dependency problems when installing software

Tags: 12.04, installation, dependencies

```
The following packages unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Depends: libc-bin (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.3) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.4 already installed   
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.4) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.3 already installed   
             Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.4) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.4 already installed   
 libc6:i386 : Depends: libc-bin (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.3) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.4 already installed
```

What is the reason, how to solve?

Comment: For unmet dependency problem read the answer given here http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Comment: The software you are trying to install depends on an older version of libc6 than you already have installed -- so it can't be installed. What is the software you are trying to install?

Comment: I am trying to install the MockupsForDesktop,but it's failed.When the Ubuntu needs to update,it's also have the same problem!

Comment: Can you instead, **[edit]** your post and add the output of `sudo apt-get check`?

Comment: Check the solution in this url:
http://askubuntu.com/a/429236/194426

Answer (score -2):

just type the command in the terminal

```
dpkg --configure libc6
```