# apt-get upgrade failure with libc

Tags: 13.04, apt

I wanted to upgrade the unetbootin package this morning.  It was going well until I got this error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.17-0ubuntu5) but 2.17-0ubuntu5.1 is installed
 libc6:i386 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.17-0ubuntu5.1) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is installed
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.17-0ubuntu5.1) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.17-0ubuntu5.1) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is installed
             Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.17-0ubuntu5.1)
 libc6-dev:i386 : Depends: libc-dev-bin:i386 (= 2.17-0ubuntu5.1)
                  Recommends: gcc:i386 but it is not installed or
                              c-compiler:i386
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.17-0ubuntu5.1) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is installed
 libc6-x32 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.17-0ubuntu5.1) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

So I did tried the suggested `apt-get -f install`

But that resulted in the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-31 linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic linux-headers-3.8.0-19
  linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic python-central
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libc-dev-bin libc6
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc-dev-bin libc6
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 109 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/4,814 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,144 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 661066 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libc6:amd64 2.17-0ubuntu5 (using .../libc6_2.17-0ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb) ...

A copy of the C library was found in an unexpected directory:
  '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so'
It is not safe to upgrade the C library in this situation;
please remove that copy of the C library or get it out of
'/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' and try again.

dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.17-0ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.17-0ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried 
apt-get clean 
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade

But that didn't help either.  The same errors are occurring.  I'm a little uncertain as to whether I dare to reboot.  How do I fix this?

---

Output of apt-cache policy libc6

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.17-0ubuntu5) but 2.17-0ubuntu5.1 is installed
 libc6:i386 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.17-0ubuntu5.1) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is installed
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.17-0ubuntu5.1) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.17-0ubuntu5.1) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is installed
             Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.17-0ubuntu5.1)
 libc6-dev:i386 : Depends: libc-dev-bin:i386 (= 2.17-0ubuntu5.1)
                  Recommends: gcc:i386 but it is not installed or
                              c-compiler:i386
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.17-0ubuntu5.1) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is installed
 libc6-x32 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.17-0ubuntu5.1) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy libc6`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all go here `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`
move these files to `/root`: `libc-2.17.so` `libdl-2.17.so` `libm-2.17.so` `libpthread-2.17.so` `librt-2.17.so`

Commands to go into the directory `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and copy the files to `/root`,

```
sudo -s
cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
cp libc-2.17.so /root
cp libdl-2.17.so /root
cp libm-2.17.so /root
cp libpthread-2.17.so /root
cp librt-2.17.so /root
```

Then you need to launch bash with predefined `LD_PRELOAD`:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/root/libc-2.17.so:/root/libdl-2.17.so:/root/libm-2.17.so:/root/libpthread-2.17.so:/root/librt-2.17.so bash
```

Commands to remove the files in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` directory,

```
rm libc-2.17.so
rm libdl-2.17.so
rm libm-2.17.so
rm libpthread-2.17.so
rm librt-2.17.so
```

after that `dist-upgrade` or `fix-missing package` will works:

```
apt-get -f install
```

OR

```
apt-get -f dist-upgrade
```

Comment: apt-get fails.  But if I did the PRELOAD trick with it then I was able to install  process to complete.  also dist-upgrade isn't what I wanted to do just a plain install.

Comment: it works or not.

Comment: I also had to issue "sudo -s" before running PRELOAD with sudo or else it couldn't read from /root.  Thanks though that method was pretty close to what I wanted.

Comment: I actually edited your answer but it's in peer review.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Avinash Raj!

I have fix this issue by following your method. 
But with minor edit of your method:

1. `sudo`

   `cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
   cp libc-2.17.so /root
   cp libdl-2.17.so /root
   cp libm-2.17.so /root
   cp libpthread-2.17.so /root
   cp librt-2.17.so /root
   cp ld-2.17.so /root/`

`mkdir /root/i386`

and `cd /lib/i386-linux-gnu
cp libc-2.17.so /root/i386
cp libdl-2.17.so /root/i386
cp libm-2.17.so /root/i386
cp libpthread-2.17.so /root/i386
cp librt-2.17.so /root/i386
cp ld-2.17.so /root/i386`

1. Preload:
   `LD_PRELOAD=/root/libc-2.17.so:/root/libdl-2.17.so:/root/libm-2.17.so:/root/libpthread-2.17.so:/root/librt-2.17.so bash`
2. remove libs:
   `cd /lib/i386-linux-gnu
   rm libc-2.17.so 
   rm libdl-2.17.so 
   rm libm-2.17.so 
   rm libpthread-2.17.so 
   rm librt-2.17.so
   rm ld-2.17.so`

`cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
rm libc-2.17.so 
rm libdl-2.17.so 
rm libm-2.17.so 
rm libpthread-2.17.so 
rm librt-2.17.so
rm ld-2.17.so`

1. `apt-get -f install` 
   I meet error when exec this command "Cannot find file lib6"
   I recovery it from by:
   `dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb`
   and `dpkg --configure -a`
2. then I can do the dist-upgrade.
   `apt-get dist-upgrade`